# In kotlin, how to get emoji view from &#x1f608

Tags: android, kotlin, server, view, emoji

I have retrieved the message from server in android app for emoji as &#X1f601 How to get emoji view with this code(&#X1f601) in android app

```
    data {"userto":"26","userfrom":"22","message":"&#x1f608 ","msid":5745}
```

From this message code(&#x1f608), how to get emoji view in String value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val testMessage = "&#x1f608 "
textView.text = testMessage.parseAsHtml()
```

You can user parseAsHtml() for this.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, solved my big problem